# Why does my Python always say "Syntax Error" when using the (f" function?

Tags: python

Whenever I try running any programs with the (f"... function my Python always shows up a Syntax Error Message.

```
from easy_terminal import terminal

@terminal()
def hi():
    print("Hello!")


@terminal()
def hello(answer: str = "world"):
    print(f"Hello {answer}!")
```

The final line of code just doesn't run because of the final set of quotation marks in the last line. I've had a similar problem with other programs, all of which have used this function.

Comment: Which _version_ of Python?

Comment: I'm running Python 3.4.1

Comment: Well, there's your answer. https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/ - introduced in 3.6. Even for 3.4, 3.4.1 is [ancient](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f-string` feature is only available from Python 3.6 and onwards. The error might be due to using a Python version that's older than 3.6.

What to do?

1- Check your Python version using:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

If your Python version is below 3.6, you would need to update it to use `f-strings`.

If your Python version is 3.6 or above and you're still facing issues, then the error might be something else, not related to the use of `f-strings`. In that case, you could share the exact error message you're getting for further assistance.

2- Ensure that you're not using any unusual characters within the `f-string`. It should follow this format:

```
variable = 'world'
print(f'Hello, {variable}!')
```

Output:  Hello, world!

Here the `f` outside the quotation marks denotes that it is a formatted string, and the curly braces `{}` are used to evaluate variables within the string.